# What is relocating allocator for buffers in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, configure

What is this option and how to enable it when running `./configure`?

```
Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`glibc` documentation](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/glibc/libc_51.html):

> Any system of dynamic memory allocation has overhead: the amount of space it uses is more than the amount the program asks for. The relocating memory allocator achieves very low overhead by moving blocks in memory as necessary, on its own initiative.

Reading through the `configure` script it looks like this memory allocator is used when better ones are not available. In particular, on my system it looks like "Doug Lea's new malloc from the GNU C Library" takes precedence over the relocating allocator.

Comment: So, how do I enable it?

Comment: @Amumu, I'm not sure that you can. It's determined by other libraries libraries like `glibc` and your OS. Letting `configure` make decisions like this is usually a good idea anyway; I'm not sure why you would want to force Emacs to use an inferior memory allocator.

Comment: I'm just curious if it is possible to change or not. Of course if it is inferior, I won't use it.

Comment: @Amumu, I'm only saying it's inferior because other methods are preferred in the `configure` script. I don't actually know enough about memory management to say for certain.